# How to insert line breaks in strings

Tags: libreoffice-calc, libreoffice-basic

How to insert line breaks when writing macros in libreoffice calc?

e.g:

```
oCell.SetString("hello /? world!")
```

Out:

```
hello
world!
```

Comment: `oCell.setString("Hello" & `[**Chr**](https://help.libreoffice.org/7.3/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/03120102.html)`(10) & "world!")`

Comment: @JohnSUN If this is a working solution, please write an answer. Comments are not for answers.

Comment: @thebusybee Yes, I know what the answer should be - tell in detail about the CR and LF, about the CHR() function, about the features of text breaks in spreadsheet cells. If all this is described, it will be a useful answer. I'm sorry, I don't have time for that right now, an air raid alert has been announced again, Kyiv is being shelled again. If someone can write the correct answer, then I will be very happy.

Comment: @JohnSUN If you're located in Ukraine, our thoughts are with you. We have just received refugees in our home, it's one thing we can do right now. All the best!

Answer (score 3):

As explained in the help docs at [Inserting Line Breaks in Cells](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/shared/guide/breaking_lines.html), a line break in Calc is ASCII 10. So use the [Chr](https://help.libreoffice.org/latest/en-US/text/sbasic/shared/03120102.html) function.

```
oCell.setString("Hello" & Chr(10) & "world!")
```

P.S. to JohnSUN, who wrote this example: We are praying for you and those close to you during this difficult time.